# Using php variable in HTML

Tags: php, html

I am using a php variable in html. `$userProfile['institute']` is displaying correct value whenever `$userProfile['institute']` is non-empty. When `$userProfile['institute']` is empty , it display '/'. What may be the issue here ?

```
Institute: <input type="text" name="institute" value=<?php echo $userProfile['institute']?> /><br />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a set of quotes for your value attribute

```
value="<?php echo $userProfile['institute']?>"
```

Comment: It is good practice to use **htmlentities** to prevent injection attacks.   <?= htmlentities($userProfile['institute']) ?>

Answer (score 0):

You should add double quotes around it like this (like you have wrapped value of type and institute attributes )

```
Institute: <input type="text" name="institute" value=" <?php echo $userProfile['institute']?>" /><br />
```